# Shell Checking user privilege of multi line Variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, privileges

I am trying to write a script that, at some point, needs to check the user privileges of multiple folders.
The paths are stored in a variable, each path in a new line.

So far I have this:

```
output=$PATH
output=$(echo "$output" | tr ':' '\n' | sort )                                                                                                                                                         
arr=($(echo "$output"))                                                                                                                                                                                                           
for i in "$arr"                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
do                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    echo "$i"                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    if ! [[ -x $i ]]; then                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        echo "You are missing execute Permission on
        echo "$i"                                                                                                                                                                                  
    fi                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
done
```

The output contains several paths, in my case the content of my `$PATH` variable.

With the first line I try to convert the multi line variable into an array
and then iterate over all array elements.

When I run the code it only works for the first entry, the `echo "$i"` only displays `/bin` before exiting the loop.

So I guess I did not convert the multi line variable to an array.

Comment: Ok I edited my initial post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
    for i in "$arr"
```

with:

```
    for i in "${arr[@]}"
```

`$arr` refers to only the first element of an array.  `{$arr[@]}` will expand to all elements, each as a separate word.

Also, if you have bash 4.0 or newer, the following can create `arr` in one step:

```
mapfile -t arr <<<"${PATH//:/$'\n'}"
```

Comment: I tried something with mapfile already but it seems mapfile is not build in on OS X 10.12
So I think other solution is more "portable"

Comment: @NIoSaT Sorry about that.   `mapfile` does require bash 4.0 (circa 2009) or better.   Mac OSX uses bash 3.2 which dates to 2006.

Comment: yeah OS X has some outdated stuff...